# Утечки памяти (C++)

Tags: память, c++

Под утечками памяти понимают утечки при работе приложения или память может не освобождаться даже после завершения работы программы? Насколько я понимаю, при завершении работы программы ОС освобождает всю память, занимаемую им. Если так, то какие бывают способы засорения памяти после завершения работы программы?

Comment: Кстати, помимо памяти, могут утекать и другие сущности (хэндлы, объекты GDI и т.п.)

Answer (score 4):

Обычно всей памятью управляет ядро ОС (возможно есть какие-нибудь "огороженные" решения с быстрым прямым доступом к памяти... но тут наверное будет совсем другая ситуация) и если у него нормально все с управлением памятью, то оно заберет ее назад после работы программы и выдаст ее другой софтине.

Т.е. да, "под утечками памяти понимают утечки при работе приложения".

Comment: Освободится ли автоматически память при использовании таких механизмов как выделение памяти в адресном пространстве другого процесса или при выделении памяти для проецируемых в память файлов?

Comment: Я пологаю, что это будет зависеть от реализации данных механизмов в ОСи. Подробнее сказать не могу, т.к. никогда так глубоко не копал.